# Help! No brightness slider in the settings (ubuntu 16.04 desktop with nvidia GTX960)

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, brightness, backlight

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my system, cpu:amd fx 6300. There is no setting to change the screen brightness. Earlier I was using deepin os 15.2 and the brightness slider worked perfectly.

I have tried following solutions:

- Installed `xbacklight`
- Installed brightness indicator - on clicking the icon in the panel,it
  says `No backlights were found on your system`
- Try to edit `xorg.conf` file but i don't have this files
- `sudo apt-get install xdotool` and creating a keyboard shortcut

but still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally this worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

Still I wish I could get a normal slider in the settings menu...

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted answer as it does not solve the OP's question.

Comment: Great !! It worked.